# ColdFusion 11 reading mulit-level JSON file

Tags: json, coldfusion-11

I have a functioning ColdFusion 11 site that pulls in a JSON file and deserialize's it and I am able to output the contents. The JSON that works looks like this:

```
[
 {"body":"some text goes here", 
  "link":"a link is here",
  "name":"name of product goes here",
  "language":"language goes here",
  "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"],
  "initiative":"initiative content goes here",
  "start_date":"start date goes here",
  "categories":["cat1","cat2","cat3"]
  }
```

Now they have given me a new JSON file that has more levels and I can't figure out how to work down to the new levels to the same data.

NEW JSON

```
[
 {
  "self_study":
   [
    {
     "categories":["Cat1","Cat2"],
     "link":"some link",
     "initiative":"initiative content goes here",
     "language":"language goes here",
     "name":"name of product",
     "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"],
     "body":"some text goes here"
    }
   ],
  "scheduled":
   [
    {
     "categories":["Cat1","Cat2"],
     "link":"some link",
     "initiative":"initiative content goes here",
     "language":"language goes here",
     "name":"name of product",
     "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"],
     "body":"some text goes here"
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

With the first JSON file I am able to loop through the data using CFLOOP

```
<cffile action="read" file="#ExpandPath("./MoocJson.json")#" variable="myxml">
<cfset mydoc = deserializedJSON(myxml)>
<cfdump var="#mydoc#">   <!--- this dumps out the JSON in Array format --->

<cfoutput> My Doc Length = #arraylen(mydoc)#</cfoutput>

<!--- Loop through Array of mydoc and out put content --->
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(mydoc)#" index="i">
<cfset Course = mydoc[i]>

#Course.Name# <br>
#Course.body# <br>
#Course.language# <br>
#Course.link# <br>
#Course.initiative# <br>
#Course.start_date# <br>
#ArrayToList(Course.tags)# <br>
#ArrayToList(Course.categories)# <br>

</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
<!--- End of Code --->
```

For the CFDUMP I get this structure:

```
Array(1)
 Struct(scheduled)
   Array(1)
    Struct(my data)
 Struct(self_study)
   Array(1)
    Struct(my data)
```

Any thoughts on how to navigate down through the multi-level JSON?

Comment: For the new JSON file, there are multiple items under scheduled and self_study arrays.

Comment: What does "navigate down" mean? Describe what you want to do. Also, why is that variable called `myxml`? I don't see any XML anywhere here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON arrays are enclosed in square brackets [] and structures in curly braces {}.

The call to deserialize JSON does all the work for you. Taking your second file its an array of structs that contains array of structs.

So if you want the first element from each array:

```
mydoc[1].self_study[1].categories[1]
mydoc[1].self_study[1].initiative
```

obviously you can use all the array operations on the arrays and the struct operations on the struct. Hope that is enough info to get you going.

Comment: Thanks - this put me in the right ballpark not just for this part of the page, but another function also.